# how to receive media files from a WhatsApp user using AWS lex, lambda and Twilio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, whatsapp, amazon-lex

I am trying to write a chatbot where a user (when prompted by lex) can send a pdf file or ideally other common formats as a simple attachment file in the WhatsApp chat such that the lambda function can then take this file and store it in a S3 bucket. I know that lex does not support media file etc and so I was planning on using Twilio to get the media file (I am already using Twilio to connect my lex bot to WhatsApp anyway).

I can send media files/messages from my lambda function to the WhatsApp user with no problem (I tried to start here and work backwards to get to recieving) but struggle to see how exactly I would receive and store a file in the most optimum/easy way for AWS. I have found guides where people have used flask to do this but quite frankly I'd rather use a more simple way then this and was wondering if there is a better and more simple method that I am missing.

I am a beginner when it comes to coding and so would really prefer not coding in anything other than python. If I need to use another language that's fine but ideally would prefer not to.

I don't really have a clue on how to even approach it. I have looked for relevant guides specifically with AWS but cant find any.